Issue when creating TableAdapters using Devart Universal

I'm having the following error when trying to add a table adapter using Devart's Donet adapter. Also I seem unable to add via nuget devart.universal.mysql
I'm using the universal one not the mysql specific.
Any help is appreciated.
PD: Their support page seems to be down.
I'm hoping to fix this error.


Thank you for your report. We have reproduced the issue with the TableAdapter in dotConnect Universal and will notify you once it is fixed.
The page https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html is working. Please try clearing your cache or using a different browser.

